# Passing a image array from Python to C bring broken data

Tags: python, c, arrays, numpy, scipy

If I define numpy array manually like this

```py
dataArray = numpy.array(
    [[ 93, 136,  10,   0,   0,  10, 136,  93],
     [107, 134, 135,   9,   9, 142, 134, 105],
     [ 10, 104, 127, 134, 134, 127, 100,  10],
     [  0,  10,  94, 116, 116,  95,   9,   0],
     [  0,   8, 115, 107, 107, 114,   7,   0],
     [  7, 123,  99,  83,  83, 101, 116,   8],
     [103,  88,  75,   8,   8,  75,  89, 103],
     [ 44,  62,   7,   0,   0,   7,  62,  44]]
)
```

C-code reads array definitely clear

```
nexus.c: PyArray_type test OK.
nexus.c: NDIM = 2: 8 8 
[93 136 10]
[107 134 135]
[10 104 127]
nexus.c: GETPTR(0,0) = 93
nexus.c: GETPTR(0,1) = 136
```

If I read image into array

```py
from skimage import io    
image = io.imread('..\\data\\cross_8_8.bmp')
```

C-code reads garbage

```
nexus.c: PyArray_type test OK.
nexus.c: NDIM = 2: 8 8 
[690269 1569196544 159876715]
[1802700800 488043 1399028487]
[1505872867 -2013256704 690269]
nexus.c: GETPTR(0,0) = 690269
nexus.c: GETPTR(0,1) = 2696
```

Even tricks like this don't work

```py
image = io.imread('..\\data\\cross_8_8.bmp')
dataArray = numpy.array(image)
rothwell.set1(dataArray)
```

Note source data in both cases exactly the same

```py
image = io.imread('..\\data\\cross_8_8.bmp')    
dataArray = numpy.array(
    [[ 93, 136,  10,   0,   0,  10, 136,  93],
     [107, 134, 135,   9,   9, 142, 134, 105],
     [ 10, 104, 127, 134, 134, 127, 100,  10],
     [  0,  10,  94, 116, 116,  95,   9,   0],
     [  0,   8, 115, 107, 107, 114,   7,   0],
     [  7, 123,  99,  83,  83, 101, 116,   8],
     [103,  88,  75,   8,   8,  75,  89, 103],
     [ 44,  62,   7,   0,   0,   7,  62,  44]]
)    
print(image)
print()
print(dataArray)
```

```
[[ 93 136  10   0   0  10 136  93]
 [107 134 135   9   9 142 134 105]
 [ 10 104 127 134 134 127 100  10]
 [  0  10  94 116 116  95   9   0]
 [  0   8 115 107 107 114   7   0]
 [  7 123  99  83  83 101 116   8]
 [103  88  75   8   8  75  89 103]
 [ 44  62   7   0   0   7  62  44]]

[[ 93 136  10   0   0  10 136  93]
 [107 134 135   9   9 142 134 105]
 [ 10 104 127 134 134 127 100  10]
 [  0  10  94 116 116  95   9   0]
 [  0   8 115 107 107 114   7   0]
 [  7 123  99  83  83 101 116   8]
 [103  88  75   8   8  75  89 103]
 [ 44  62   7   0   0   7  62  44]]
```

Complete nexus.c

```c
#include <Python.h>
#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_8_API_VERSION
#include "numpy/arrayobject.h"

static PyObject* rothwell_set1(PyObject* self, PyObject* args)
{
  PyArrayObject *listObj;

  if(PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O!", &PyArray_Type, &listObj))
    printf("nexus.c: PyArray_type test OK.\n");
  else
    printf("nexus.c: PyArray_type test FAIL.\n");

  printf("nexus.c: NDIM = %d: ", PyArray_NDIM(listObj));

  int nd = PyArray_NDIM(listObj);   //number of dimensions
  npy_intp *shape = PyArray_DIMS(listObj);  // npy_intp array of length nd showing length in each dim.
  for (int i=0; i<nd; ++i) printf("%d ", shape[i]);

  printf("\n");

  npy_intp *data = PyArray_DATA(listObj);

  printf("[%d %d %d]\n", data[0],  data[1],  data[2]);
  printf("[%d %d %d]\n", data[8],  data[9],  data[10]);
  printf("[%d %d %d]\n", data[16], data[17], data[18]);

  printf("nexus.c: GETPTR(0,0) = %d\n", *(int *)PyArray_GETPTR2(listObj, 0, 0));
  printf("nexus.c: GETPTR(0,1) = %d\n", *(int *)PyArray_GETPTR2(listObj, 0, 1));

  return Py_BuildValue("i", 1);
}

static char rothwell_docs[] =
    "set1( ): rothwell set of properties 1\n";

static PyMethodDef rothwell_funcs[] =
{
    {"set1", (PyCFunction)rothwell_set1, METH_VARARGS, rothwell_docs},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

static struct PyModuleDef rothwell_def =
{
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "rothwell", /* name of module */
    "rothwell filter\n", /* module documentation, may be NULL */
    -1, /* size of per-interpreter state of the module, or -1 if the module keeps state in global variables. */
    rothwell_funcs
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_rothwell(void)
{
    import_array();
    return PyModule_Create(&rothwell_def);
}
```

### UPD: solution

**@WarrenWeckesser** was right. The code below works correctly

```c
  switch(PyArray_ITEMSIZE(listObj))
  {
    case 1:
        uint8_t *data8 = PyArray_DATA(listObj);
        printf("[%d %d %d]\n", data8[0],  data8[1],  data8[2]);
        break;
    case 2:
        uint16_t *data16 = PyArray_DATA(listObj);
        printf("[%d %d %d]\n", data16[0],  data16[1],  data16[2]);
        break;
    default:
        uint32_t *data32 = PyArray_DATA(listObj);
        printf("[%d %d %d]\n", data32[0],  data32[1],  data32[2]);
  }
```

Comment: try printing `img.dtype` and `dataArray.dtype` as well as `img.flags` and `dataArray.flags`

Comment: Which operating system are you using?  More importantly, which C compiler?  I ask because in Microsoft C, an `int` is 32 bits.

Comment: I use MS compiller, if it matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The numpy array `dataArray` contains either 32 or 64 bit integers, which matches the C declaration `npy_intp *data = PyArray_DATA(listObj);` for your platform.  Actually, it looks like your `int`s are 32 bit.  Note that `0*256**3 + 10*256**2 + 136*256+93 = 690269`.  That is, the 4 byte [little-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) representation of the value 690269 is [93, 136,  10,   0], which are the first four values in the first row of your image.

The array returned by `imread` is 8 bit integers, so that C declaration is no longer correct.  The C code "thinks" the data is 32 bit integers, so the first value is 690269.  Similarly, the second value printed by the C code is 1569196544, whose 4 byte little-endian representation is [0, 10, 136, 93].  Those values are the second group of 4 in the first row of your image.

In your Python code, you can use `image.dtype` and `image.itemsize` to check the data type and the number of bytes in each element of the array `image`.  There is a corresponding C API; for example, to get the number of bytes of each element, you can use [`PyArray_ITEMSIZE(PyArrayObject *arr)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.array.html#c.PyArray_ITEMSIZE).